Is this an OK way to check if a function needs thread synchronisation?
Because I don't want to pay the performance penalty of synchronisation a function between threads if only one thread is ever going to call it, I was wondering if this is an acceptable way to check:
struct MyLogger
{
    static inline std::thread::id main_thread_id = std::this_thread::get_id(); // THIS CAN ONLY BE INITIALISED BY THE MAIN THREAD ON STARTUP
    std::atomic_flag lock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    bool bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads = false;
    
    void log(const char* something)
    {
        if (std::this_thread::get_id() != main_thread_id)
        {// THEN A THREAD OTHER THAN THE MAIN THREAD IS CALLING THIS, NEED THREAD SYNCHRONISATION
            bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads = true;
        }

        if (bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads)
        {
            while (lock.test_and_set());
            std::cout << something;
            lock.clear();
        }
        else
            std::cout << something;




    }
};


bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads isn't synchronized.

Also, every worker thread will repeatedly reset bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads unnecessarily, so you should use something like if ((!bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads) && (std::this_thread::get_id() != main_thread_id)). Once bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads has been set, you don't need to do the get_id checks anymore.

@tkausl Ah yes, so basically the idea is impossible right? If I need to make that atomic then I may as well just use the atomic to synchronise. Or is that still better performance?

@RemyLebeau Ah yes, but bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads needs to be atomic too right?

If there were an easy costless way to write code that could automatically synchronize only when needed, then it would be widely known because everyone would want to be using it. So because such a thing is not already being widely used, it stands to reason that it isn't generally possible.

Don't conditionally enable multi-thread synchronization at runtime based on a second thread calling your code. Do it at compile time.  And use asserts to validate your single-threaded assumptions.  I suspect you won't really notice the performance hit at all.

A technique to make single logging thread safe and performant is to push all log messages to an atomic stack.  Then when the stack gets too large, you swap the stack with another one atomically. Then on another thread, you reverse the stack and flush it to disk.

@selbie Why do you reverse the stack? A list/array/vector is a stack, why do you need to reverse it when you flush to disk? Also do you know a way of using an atomic stack without two atomic writes, lock on, lock off?

@TheUndeadFish While I do not contradict you, that thought is a good recipe to prevent any advancement or new inventions. So tread carefully.

As others have already pointed out, your use of bIsCalledFromMultipleThreads is not thread safe.
You can use concepts like (Windows) InterlockedIncrement or std::atomic with  native numeric types.
The benefit of such atomic "test and set" operations is that they may not need any synchronization because it can be an atomic hardware operation.
Something like
std::atomic<int> sharedAtomicCounter = 0;
...
if(++sharedAtomicCounter == 1)
{
    // I am the first
}
else
{
    // I have to do something to wait
}
--sharedAtomicCounter;

I recommend to have a look on the synchronization classes / functions that your operating system provides and their benefits and drawbacks.
Some mechanisms like Windows CRITICAL_SECTION actually use such atomic "test and set" operations and have very little impact when there is no concurrent access.
They should be as fast as your code but may be easier to use.
The synchronized code will be very quick when there is no concurrent access and performs the slower synchronization only when needed.
Some of those fast synchronization mechanisms may have a few limitations in which scenarios they can be used, e.g. for recursive locking or among multiple processes, but they are usually fine for all simple scenarios.
I am not really aware which locking mechanisms the standard librariy uses but I guess if you find and pick the correct STL synchronization class then you should get the same operating system specific functionality.

If I use the c++ types from the standard library it's cross-platform, I think that's good. "modify-and-get", are you thinking of something like "test and set"? C++ has that.

@Zebrafish: Yes, "test and set" was the phrase I was looking for. std::atomic, std::atomic_flag and (C) InterlockedIncrement belong to that category.
